# How to load a TypeScript Module from node_modules via Angular 13

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I am currently trying to update a project from Angular 5 to 13. In Version 5, it was possible to install a typescript module (not transpiled) under node_modules and then use it in the main project by importing it. This seems to no longer work in Angular 13. When running it, I get the error:

> **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')**

Example Module:

structure:

```
ng-test
  package.json
  index.ts
  src
    test
      test.module.ts
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.ts",
  "directories": {
    "test": "test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

index.ts:

```
export {TestModule} from './src/test/test.module';
```

test.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [],
  providers: []
})
export class TestModule {
}
```

The main project is a basic angular 13 project, created via `ng new` and the package is installed via git+ssh (e.g: `npm install git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/company-name/package-name`). The module is then simply added to the `app.module.ts` via an import:

```
import {TestModule} from 'ng-test';

@NgModule({
   ...
   imports: [
     ...
     TestModule
   ]
})
```

How can I make this work in angular 13?

Comment: make shure that module can be used with angular 13+ version

Comment: I found out, that the include config for the ts node_modules folder has to be in tsconfig.app.json. It will not work when added to tsconfig.json. Also, when working with symlinks, it will no longer be enough to add "preserveSymlinks" to "compilerOptions". You also have to add it to builder options in angular.json.

Comment: https://update.angular.io/?v=5.0-6.1 Angular provides an upgrade guide but only supports upgrading one major version at a time (5 -> 6 -> 7 -> ...)

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. But my situation is, after logined in to home page, if it goes on navigate to some other route, the error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')" occurs. I haven't still figure out why!